# How can I call a .C function compiled with Matlab Coder in R?

Tags: r, c, matlab, matlab-coder

I would like to call a C function compiled using Matlab Coder in R for later use in a Shiny app. How can I go about doing this. The top of the .C function looks like this:

```c
double ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V1(double TransferredYesNo,
                                          double BleedDisYesNo,
                                          double PreOpAlbumin, double PreOpHCT,
                                          double ASAClass, double ComplexYesNo)
```

and the file name for the c function is "ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V1.c"

I have very limited knowledge of R and .C and I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Difficult to give a precise answer without knowing the exact C libraries needed by Matlab C Coder for this function. However perhaps this gives you a start point : https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/07/using-r-calling-c-code-with-rcpp/

Comment: You need to compile the function with the Gnu C compiler at the command line with `R CMD SHLIB file.c` and then call it from **R** with `.C`. More about this can be found in the [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) manual.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried R CMD SHLIB file.c but it resulted in the following error:   clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V1.c -o ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V1.o
In file included from ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V1.c:13:
In file included from ./ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V1.h:16:
./rtwtypes.h:42:10: fatal error: 'tmwtypes.h' file not found
#include "tmwtypes.h"

Comment: As anticipated, tmwtypes.h is one of the Matlab libraries you'll need to include, see https://fr.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/mapping-matlab-types-to-cc-types.html

Comment: It will not be easy to compile this file. It has lots of dependencies. Start by reading the documentation to MATLAB Coder.

Comment: @Waldi  Okay, so I found the "tmwtypes.h" file to the folder and now received the following errors:    In file included from ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V1.c:14:
./CompactEnsemble.h:25:44: error: unknown type name 'boolean_T'
void CompactEnsemble_ensemblePredict(const boolean_T obj_IsCached[30],
                                           ^
In file included from ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V1.c:15:
./rt_nonfinite.h:22:8: error: unknown type name 'real_T'
extern real_T rtInf;
       ^
./rt_nonfinite.h:23:8: error: unknown type name 'real_T'
extern real_T rtMinusInf;

Comment: As stated by @CrisLuengo, you'll need to find all dependencies requested by Matlab Coder before being able to compile this function. I haven't done this myself, so that I won't be able to help further.

Answer (score 1):

When you'd like to compile MATLAB Coder generated code on your own or pull it into an IDE, you can [package](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/package-code-for-other-development-environments.html) your code and **all** of its compile-time and run-time dependencies using Coder. For example:

```matlab
codegen yourFunction -args -config:lib
packNGo('codegen/lib/yourFunction')
```

That produces `yourFunction.zip` containing generated sources, dependent headers/sources, and any library dependencies.

The documentation link above shows how to do this in the Coder App.

Once you have that ZIP file, you can unzip it and use the command noted in the comments by @tpetzoldt
[`R CMD SHLIB`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html)  along with the extension system to compile **all** of the C files present in that ZIP file.